# Developing Social Network App using Spring Boot or Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am planning to develop a Social Network App using Java. I recently learn Spring MVC and Spring Boot. I
am confuse which one is better to use for my app. Can you please give me some suggestion which one is
better to use? And what to use for front end as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ehsan, Spring boot is a "way" to create your software, and spring mvc is a structure that how you build your software within Spring Boot! Spring has many frameworks, such as JPA and Security. You need both and more.

I use Angular and I like it. But, you can choose between react, vue and others.

The frontend does not need to depend on the backend, requests will be using API.